# OAuth MSAL4J Office365 -> AccessToken error "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, exchangewebservices, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I am currently trying to use the MSAL4J library to get an AccessToken for a ConfidentialClientApplication. I already get the token, but when I pass it to Exchange I get the error "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood" . I inspected the token with jwt.io and I can see that there is no "scp" field which means there probably are no scopes but I don't know why.

The Java Code for accessing the token:

```
String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
IClientSecret createFromSecret = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);

Builder builder = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, createFromSecret).authority(aUTHORITY).validateAuthority(true);
ConfidentialClientApplication application = builder.build();
HashSet<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();
scopes.add("https://outlook.office.com/.default");
ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParameters = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(scopes).build();
CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> acquireTokenFuture = application.acquireToken(clientCredentialParameters);
IAuthenticationResult iAuthenticationResult = acquireTokenFuture.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

iAuthenticationResult = acquireTokenFuture.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have added the necessary api permissions and approved them with the admin account:
[image: api permissions]

any ideas whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found the answer by myself. In my case I had to add the permissions for exchange, the microsoft graph (as it is used in every example I found) does not work in this scenario or is not sufficient.
[image: Correct Permissions]